# Can't identify seed pods

Tags: identification

[image: identify-please]

I live in New Zealand and found several of these seed pods in an old garden. I was told they were crocosmia but I have yet to see any photos with the netting-like stuff around them. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

If it is [**Crocosmia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocosmia) (and I'd love to see more pictures from other angles), it's not a seed pod, but a *[corm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corm)*.

Crocosmia (Montbretia) has a fleshy corm with a fibrous outer layer - see the sample image below:

[image: crocosmia corms]

([Source](https://mikesgardenguide.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/understanding-summer-bulbs/))